# React import svg having TS Error: "Cannot find module '../images/bar.svg'."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, import

in `.tsx` file, I could import `.svg` file, setting following `tsconfig.json` and `index.d.ts` files.

**tsconfig.json**

```
"compilerOptions": {...},
"include": ["./app/src/index.d.ts"]
```

**index.d.ts**

```js
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

then I imported like this
`import image from "../images/bar.svg";`

No webpack compile error, no problem with using the image, but just got the ts error from vscode:
`Cannot find module '../images/bar.svg'.`

How can I remove this error?